# import boto3 ImportError: No module named boto3 docker container

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, pip, boto3

I am trying to deploying code from bitbucket to AWS Elastic beanstalk. While deploying code from bitbucket i am facing import boto3 problem.

But in my old docker image working fine.

**OLD Docker File**

```
ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1    
 RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base python3-dev python3 libffi-dev libressl-dev bash git gettext ca-certificates curl groff less zip libstdc++ jq \
  && curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \
  && python3 get-pip.py \
  && pip install --upgrade --use-feature=2020-resolver six awscli awsebcli \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* 
  
 RUN apk --no-cache add python py-pip \
  && pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade pip \
  && pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade --user boto3 boto
 
 RUN apk update && \
     apk add --no-cache git openssh perl && \
     pip install pytz tzlocal
```

in **Python2.7** everything working fine. when i am upgrading python version from **2.7 to 3.7** getting this import boto3 error.

**Docker File**

```
ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1    
 RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base python3-dev python3 libffi-dev libressl-dev bash git gettext ca-certificates curl groff less zip libstdc++ jq py3-pip\
  && pip3 install  --upgrade six awscli awsebcli \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* 
  
 RUN apk --no-cache add python3 py3-pip\
  && python3 -m venv env-env \
  && source env-env/bin/activate \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
  && pip3 install --upgrade boto3 
 RUN apk update  && \
     apk add --no-cache git openssh perl && \
     python3 -m venv env-env && \
     source env-env/bin/activate && \
     pip3 install pytz tzlocal
 ENV PATH "$PATH:~/.local/bin"
 
 ADD deployment-scripts /opt/deployment-scripts
```

**Python Script**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
from time import strftime, sleep
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone
```

when i am running this script file i got

> import boto3 ImportError: No module named boto3

i had tried

> python3 -m pip install boto3

but i get same error while running script.
help me out from this.

As per python update documet
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.16.56/guide/migrationpy3.html

we have to upgrade from python 2.7 to python3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only installed `boto3` inside your `env-env` virtual environment. If you want to make use of that module, you'll need to activate the environment first.

Compare:

```
/ # which python3
/usr/bin/python3
/ # python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 12 2021, 20:44:22)
[GCC 10.3.1 20210424] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

With:

```
/ # . env-env/bin/activate
(env-env) / # which python3
/env-env/bin/python3
(env-env) / # python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 12 2021, 20:44:22)
[GCC 10.3.1 20210424] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>>
```

Another solution is to not use the virtual environment. It's not
clear why you're creating it, since you're building a container image
-- the normal reasons for creating an isolated Python environment for
the most part don't apply, because the container itself will be your
isolation.

---

On an unrelated note, this...

```
 ENV PATH "$PATH:~/.local/bin"
```

...doesn't do what you think it does. The `ENV` keyword doesn't expand `~`, so you end up with a path that contains a literal `~` which isn't going to match anything. Additionall, `$PATH` is going to match the value of `$PATH` on your host, *not* whatever the container default is, so you may end up defining a value for `$PATH` containing a variety of directories that don't exist.

---

There's a lot going on in your Dockerfile that I'm not sure is
necessary (since I'm not running your code). This was sufficient to
allow me to write Python code that uses the `boto3` module:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    build-base \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    py3-cryptography \
    py3-pip \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    zip

RUN pip3 install --upgrade \
    boto3 \
    pytz \
    tzlocal
```

Comment: when i build without virtual environment i got "warning: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv". that's why i use env variable

Comment: thanks for quick response. I had try 
RUN apk --no-cache add python3 py3-pip\
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
  && pip3 install --upgrade boto3
but i got same error boto3 import error.

Comment: You have two choices (a) ignore the error or (b) correctly activate the virtual environment. Either solution will work, although (a) is perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: RUN apk --no-cache add python3 py3-pip\
  && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
  && python3 -m pip install --upgrade boto3 
this should work am i right larsks?

Comment: I've update the answer with a Dockerfile that works for me.

Comment: i had tryed this too, but i got same error.

Comment: thanks @Larsks, It was working fine. problem was my variable